# Computer cannot display on all 4 displays

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display, displayport

I recently got a (free) computer monitor and I want to try and hook it up. My PC seems to detect the 4th display, but it seems to be maxing out at 3. Originally I thought my cable or DispayPort to HDMI adapter was bad, but that does not seem to be the case as I now have the new monitor connected with a known-working HDMI cable through the adapter. Now my original, working monitor will not turn on through the graphic card's built-in HDMI port. Not sure exactly what's going on here.

Interestingly, the PC seems to detect the presence of all 4 displays (I get a chime whenever I plug the 4th display in - HDMI or DisplayPort, whichever the 4th one is gets a chime) as indicated by the Display Settings panel, but it only displays on 3 of them.

[image]

Here's my system specs according to the AMD Raedon Settings panel:

```
Graphics Card Manufacturer - Powered by AMD
Graphics Chipset - AMD Radeon (TM) R7 360 Series
Device ID - 665F
Vendor ID - 1002
SubSystem ID - 22B9
SubSystem Vendor ID - 1458
Revision ID - 81
Bus Type - PCI Express 3.0
Current Bus Settings - PCI Express 3.0 x16
BIOS Version - 015.049.000.002
BIOS Part Number - xxx-xxx-xxx
BIOS Date - 2015/06/14 23:24
Memory Size - 2048 MB
Memory Type - GDDR5
Memory Clock - 1625 MHz
Core Clock - 1200 MHz
Total Memory Bandwidth - 104 GByte/s
Memory Bit Rate - 6.50 Gbps
2D Driver File Path - /REGISTRY/MACHINE/SYSTEM/ControlSet001/Control/Class/{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}/0000


Radeon Settings Version - 2017.0922.1659.28737
Driver Packaging Version - 17.30.1091.1011-170922a-318486C
Provider - Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
2D Driver Version - 8.1.1.1614
Direct3D® Version - 9.14.10.01304
OpenGL® Version - 6.14.10.13492
OpenCL™ Version - 22.19.677.257
AMD Mantle Version - 9.1.10.0220
AMD Mantle API Version - 102400
AMD Audio Driver Version - 10.0.1.5
Vulkan™ Driver Version - 1.6.0
Vulkan™ API Version - 1.0.51

Radeon Software Version - 17.7
Radeon Software Edition - Crimson ReLive
Graphics Chipset - AMD Radeon (TM) R7 360 Series
Memory Size - 2048 MB
Memory Type - GDDR5
Core Clock - 1200 MHz
Windows Version - Windows 10 (64 bit)
System Memory - 16 GB
CPU Type - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
```

Below are my system specs (as reported by Speccy (great program):

```
Operating System
    Windows 10 Home 64-bit
CPU
    Intel Core i7 4770 @ 3.40GHz    43 °C
    Haswell 22nm Technology
RAM
    16.0GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 804MHz (11-11-11-28)
Motherboard
    Hewlett-Packard 2AF7 (SOCKET 0) 43 °C
Graphics
    HP w2338h (1920x1080@59Hz)
    DELL 1908FP (1280x1024@60Hz)
    DELL 1704FPV (1280x1024@60Hz)
    2048MB ATI AMD Radeon R7 360 Series (Gigabyte)  47 °C
Storage
    1863GB Seagate ST2000DM001-1CH164 (SATA)    37 °C
    3726GB Seagate Backup+ Desk SCSI Disk Device (USB (SATA))   48 °C
    14GB Generic Flash Disk USB Device (USB)
Optical Drives
    hp DVD-RAM SW820
Audio
    AMD High Definition Audio Device

CPU
        Intel Core i7 4770
            Cores   4
            Threads 8
            Name    Intel Core i7 4770
            Code Name   Haswell
            Package Socket 1150 LGA
            Technology  22nm
            Specification   Intel Core i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
            Family  6
            Extended Family 6
            Model   C
            Extended Model  3C
            Stepping    3
            Revision    C0
            Instructions    MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, SSE4.2, Intel 64, NX, VMX, AES, AVX, AVX2, FMA3
            Virtualization  Supported, Disabled
            Hyperthreading  Supported, Enabled
            Fan Speed   1169 RPM
            Bus Speed   99.9 MHz
            Stock Core Speed    3400 MHz
            Stock Bus Speed 100 MHz
            Average Temperature 42 °C
                Caches
                    L1 Data Cache Size  4 x 32 KBytes
                    L1 Instructions Cache Size  4 x 32 KBytes
                    L2 Unified Cache Size   4 x 256 KBytes
                    L3 Unified Cache Size   8192 KBytes
                Cores
                        Core Speed  Multiplier  Bus Speed   Temperature Threads
                    Core 0  3896.3 MHz  x 39.0  99.9 MHz    41 °C   APIC ID: 0, 1
                    Core 1  3796.4 MHz  x 38.0  99.9 MHz    41 °C   APIC ID: 2, 3
                    Core 2  3896.3 MHz  x 39.0  99.9 MHz    44 °C   APIC ID: 4, 5
                    Core 3  3896.3 MHz  x 39.0  99.9 MHz    43 °C   APIC ID: 6, 7

Operating System
    Windows 10 Home 64-bit
    Computer type: Tablet
    Installation Date: 2/10/2018 8:52:10 PM
    Serial Number: T49TD-6VFBW-VV7HY-B2PXY-MY47H
        Windows Security Center
            Firewall    Enabled
        Windows Update
            AutoUpdate  Not configured
        Windows Defender
            Windows Defender    Disabled
        Antivirus
                Webroot SecureAnywhere
                    Antivirus   Enabled
                    Company Name    Webroot
                    Product Version 9.0.20.31
                    Virus Signature Database    Up to date
                Windows Defender
                    Antivirus   Disabled
                    Virus Signature Database    Up to date
        .NET Frameworks installed
            v4.7 Full
            v4.7 Client
            v3.5 SP1
            v3.0 SP2
            v2.0 SP2
        Internet Explorer
            Version 11.431.16299.0
        PowerShell
            Version 5.1.16299.15
        Java
                Java Runtime Environment
                    Path    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe
                    Version 8.0
                    Update  161
                    Build   12
                Java Runtime Environment
                    Path    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe
                    Version 8.0
                    Update  161
                    Build   12
        Environment Variables
            USERPROFILE C:\Users\misc
            SystemRoot  C:\WINDOWS
                User Variables
                Machine Variables
        Power Profile
            Active power scheme High performance
            Hibernation Enabled
            Turn Off Monitor after: (On AC Power)   15 min
            Turn Off Hard Disk after: (On AC Power) 20 min
            Suspend after: (On AC Power)    Never
            Screen saver    Disabled
        Uptime
                Current Session
                    Current Time    6/2/2018 1:10:09 PM
                    Current Uptime  188,031 sec (2 d, 04 h, 13 m, 51 s)
                    Last Boot Time  5/31/2018 8:56:18 AM
        Services
        TimeZone
            TimeZone    GMT -5:00 Hours
            Language    English (United States)
            Location    United States
            Format  English (United States)
            Currency    $
            Date Format M/d/yyyy
            Time Format h:mm:ss tt
        Scheduler
            6/2/2018 1:02 PM;   GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA
            6/2/2018 1:12 PM;   Adobe Flash Player Updater
            6/2/2018 1:13 PM;   Adobe Flash Player PPAPI Notifier
            6/2/2018 3:02 PM;   GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore
            6/2/2018 7:54 PM;   AutoKMS
            6/3/2018 6:10 AM;   Opera scheduled Autoupdate 1518009744
            6/3/2018 2:06 PM;   OneDrive Standalone Update Task-S-1-5-21-515206214-2944248679-1480767375-1001
            6/5/2018 7:35 AM;   HPCeeScheduleFormisc
            CCleanerSkipUAC
            Durée de vie
            StartCN
        Hotfixes
        System Folders
        Process List
        Security Options
        Device Tree

Motherboard
    Manufacturer    Hewlett-Packard
    Model   2AF7 (SOCKET 0)
    Version 1.04
    Chipset Vendor  Intel
    Chipset Model   Haswell
    Chipset Revision    06
    Southbridge Vendor  Intel
    Southbridge Model   H87
    Southbridge Revision    C1
    System Temperature  42 °C
        BIOS
            Brand   AMI
            Version 80.21
            Date    8/13/2015
        Voltage
            +3.3V   3.296 V
            CPU CORE    1.744 V
            VIN2    2.064 V
            VIN3    2.152 V
            VSB3V   3.312 V
            CMOS BATTERY    3.248 V
        PCI Data
                Slot PCI
                    Slot Type   PCI
                    Slot Usage  In Use
                    Data lanes  x16
                    Slot Designation    PCI Express x16 Slot
                    Characteristics 3.3V, Shared, PME
                    Slot Number 0
                Slot PCI
                    Slot Type   PCI
                    Slot Usage  Available
                    Data lanes  x1
                    Slot Designation    PCI Express x1 Slot 1
                    Characteristics 3.3V, Shared, PME
                    Slot Number 1
                Slot PCI
                    Slot Type   PCI
                    Slot Usage  Available
                    Data lanes  x1
                    Slot Designation    PCI Express x1 Slot 2
                    Characteristics 3.3V, Shared, PME
                    Slot Number 2
                Slot PCI
                    Slot Type   PCI
                    Slot Usage  Available
                    Data lanes  x1
                    Slot Designation    PCI Express x1 Slot 3
                    Characteristics 3.3V, Shared, PME
                    Slot Number 3
                Slot PCI-E
                    Slot Type   PCI-E
                    Slot Usage  In Use
                    Data lanes  x1
                    Slot Designation    Mini Card Slot 1
                    Characteristics 3.3V, Shared, PME
                    Slot Number 4
Graphics
        Monitor 1
            Name    HP w2338h on AMD Radeon R7 360 Series
            Current Resolution  1920x1080 pixels
            Work Resolution 1920x1040 pixels
            State   Enabled, Unsafe
            Multiple displays   Extended, Secondary, Enabled
            Monitor Width   1920
            Monitor Height  1080
            Monitor BPP 32 bits per pixel
            Monitor Frequency   59 Hz
            Device  \\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0
        Monitor 2
            Name    DELL 1908FP on AMD Radeon R7 360 Series
            Current Resolution  1280x1024 pixels
            Work Resolution 1280x984 pixels
            State   Enabled, Output devices support, Unsafe
            Multiple displays   Extended, Primary, Enabled
            Monitor Width   1280
            Monitor Height  1024
            Monitor BPP 32 bits per pixel
            Monitor Frequency   60 Hz
            Device  \\.\DISPLAY2\Monitor0
        Monitor 3
            Name    DELL 1704FPV on AMD Radeon R7 360 Series
            Current Resolution  1280x1024 pixels
            Work Resolution 1280x984 pixels
            State   Enabled, Output devices support, Unsafe
            Multiple displays   Extended, Secondary, Enabled
            Monitor Width   1280
            Monitor Height  1024
            Monitor BPP 32 bits per pixel
            Monitor Frequency   60 Hz
            Device  \\.\DISPLAY3\Monitor0
        ATI AMD Radeon (TM) R7 360 Series
            Manufacturer    ATI
            Model   AMD Radeon R7 360 Series
            Device ID   1002-665F
            Revision    82
            Subvendor   Gigabyte (1458)
            Current Performance Level   Level 0
            Current GPU Clock   300 MHz
            Current Memory Clock    1625 MHz
            Current Shader Clock    1625 MHz
            Voltage 0.001 V
            GPU Clock   1200.0 MHz
            Temperature 47 °C
            Core Voltage    0.001 V
            Driver version  22.19.677.257
            BIOS Version    xxx-xxx-xxx
            Memory Type GDDR5
            Memory  2048 MB
            Bandwidth   104.0 GB/s
                Count of performance levels : 2
                    Level 1 - "Perf Level 0"
                    Level 2 - "Perf Level 1"
```

Comment: The R7 360 can only support two legacy display connectors, DVI/HDMI. The third monitor and beyond must use a displayport connection. The only way you can use four displays will be via a MST Hub.

Comment: interesting, HDMI is considered "legacy," isn't that the standard nowadays?

I actually had 3 displays working just fine. It's the 4th one that's causing issues. In total, I've got 2 DVI, 1 HDMI, and 1 DisplayPort

Comment: The [specs](https://www.cnet.com/products/xfx-radeon-r7-360-graphics-card-radeon-r7-360-2-gb-r7360bcdfr/specs/) I found say : "Max Monitors Supported 3". Your configuration is unsupported.

Comment: @harrymc I get a 404 error trying to go to that link

Comment: I fixed the link. Note also that video cards have a limit on the total number of pixels combined on all monitors.

Comment: Hmm, ok, well now I'm down to just the HDMI and DisplayPort plugged in. I disconnected the two DVI monitors, but now I'm only displaying on the Displayport monitor, still no HDMI. Not sure if rebooting would make a difference

Comment: And actually, for that matter, even unplugging he Displayport, so that only the HDMI was plugged in, left me with no monitors

Comment: DisplayPort supports monitors in "Daisy chain", which might be more efficient. See [this link](http://multimonitorcomputer.com/solved/displayport-daisy-chaining-of-3-or-4-monitors-quick-guide.php). This is by connecting DisplayPort labeled "Out" from monitor 1 to the DisplayPort labeled "In" on the second monitor etc.

Comment: Yeah, but that involves buying new monitors since none of them support DP naively. That's why I have the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Your GPU can only support a maximum of two passive display connections
(HDMI/DVI/VGA).
The third display and beyond need to use a native DisplayPort connection,
or be via an active adapter.

According to this
[AMD article](https://support.amd.com/en-us/search/faq/170)
your only options for 4 monitors are :

1. Using DisplayPort with [Daisy chain](http://multimonitorcomputer.com/solved/displayport-daisy-chaining-of-3-or-4-monitors-quick-guide.php).
   As your monitors do not natively support DisplayPort, this might not be
   the solution for you.
2. Using an MST hub you may connect up to 6 monitors.

An MST hub seems to be your best option.
For explanation on what it does see the article
[DisplayPort MST hub [finally explained!]](http://multimonitorcomputer.com/solved/displayport-mst-hub.php).

Unfortunately, most of the hubs that support 4 ports are pretty costly,
around $100.
They usually only do the splitting of one DisplayPort 1.2 to several
DisplayPort ports, so in your case requiring also the use of the appropriate
HDMI/DVI converters.

To economize on costs,
you might be able to put your 1st and 2nd monitors on DVI or HDMI,
as you now do,
while putting the 3rd and 4th monitor on the DisplayPort.
This way you could use a cheaper 1-to-2 MST hub, with, if required,
up to two adapters to HDMI/DVI.
But better buy this MST hub and the adapters from a shop with a good
return policy, just in case this setup doesn't work.